# preload flex application with extjs

Tags: apache-flex, extjs, flex4, window, preload

in my application basically coded with extjs , i have a module coded with flex 4 the problem is that flex makes long time at the first load , so i wonder if i can preload flex before the user need it

This is the code for the ext window that host the flex application :

```
function openPdf(){
    var user = Ext.get('userName').getValue();
        PlanRs = new Ext.Window({
            width:'100%',
            autoHeight:true,
            autoScroll:true,
            html:'<iframe src ="PlanRs/index/bin-debug/index.html?user='+user+'" ></iframe>',
            bbar:[{
                text:'Close',
                handler:flexAppCloseHandler
            }]
        })         
   PlanRs.show(); 
}
```

i have tried to instantiate the window and make it invisible until user call with no success!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the Ext.Window it still isn't rendered due to ExtJS's lazy rendering mechanism. This means that the iframe isn't inserted into the DOM as long as the component isn't rendered by calling `show()` for example.

Try instantiating your Ext.Window and calling `PlanRs.render()` manually and only call `PlanRs.show()` in your `openPdf()` function.

Comment: thank you , this is the idea , by the way is there a best method to embed flex application than use of iframe ?

Comment: i don't know much of flex but my guess is that it's just an swf which is embedded the same as a flash movie so i'd recommend using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) instead of an iframe.